# SQL/Linq coding for a search feature in MVC app - best practice

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a section of an ASP MVC app I building that displays an info sheet regarding a person, then there is a button which will allow the user to search the database, to see if this person is already in the database before saving the record.  If the record exists, then the feature needs to overwrite certain fields in the DB, kind of a 'search and merge/update'.

I am pretty sure this will go beyond my LINQ skills, so I am thinking of doing a stored proc, but I wanted to poll the masses to see what the accepted best practice is for something like this.

Thank you for reading, and for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stored proc for something like this. It always depends on what you're trying to accomplish and how complex your operation is, but using a stored proc simplifies your code and will also allow you to easily replicate that behavior in other places if necessary.